# Putting a border on a link with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a bottom border on my link but despite using code pretty much straight from the internet it doesnt seem to want to work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeLqc

```
lll {
  font-weight:normal;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  background: #EEE;
  display: table;
}
```

If I wanted a thick border on the bottom of my links, how should I be doing it?

Comment: You are missing the `.` on `lll` in your CSS. It should be `.lll { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring class selectors in CSS, they must start with `.`:

```
.lll {
  font-weight:normal;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  background: #EEE;
  display: table;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hwsak

---

Here is a useful article on CSS selectors:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 2):

The selector `lll` wont work as is.

- If your class is `lll` then your code needs to be `.lll`
- If it's an ID then it needs to be `#lll`

Also, is there a reason you're using `display: table`? That probably isn't helping your link. Maybe try `display: inline-block` instead? Obviously without knowing the site you're working on it's hard to say.

But changing those two things will definitely help!

Answer (score 1):

You missed a class assignment try:

```
.lll {
 font-weight:normal;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
 background: #EEE;
 display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use dot(.) before writing the css.
It should be like

```
.lll {
  font-weight:normal;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  background: #EEE;
  display: table;
}
```